# Manjaro update showing error

Tags: bash, upgrade, manjaro

I saw a notification that "Package updates are available" so I clicked on it then click Apply but after a few moments I saw this warning:

```
Warning: installing pamac-cli (10.0.5-1) breaks dependency 'pamac-cli=10.0.5-0.2' required by pamac-flatpak-plugin
Add pamac-flatpak-plugin to remove
Warning: installing pamac-cli (10.0.5-1) breaks dependency 'pamac-cli=10.0.5-0.2' required by pamac-snap-plugin
Add pamac-snap-plugin to remove
Warning: removing pamac-gtk breaks dependency 'pamac-gtk' required by web-installer-url-handler
Add web-installer-url-handler to remove
```

But I Ignored it and clicked `close` then `Build` and then it showed me an error:

```
conflicting files:
- bash: /etc/bash.bashrc already exists in filesystem (owned by bashrc-manjaro)
- bash: /etc/skel/.bashrc already exists in filesystem (owned by bashrc-manjaro)
- lsb-release: /etc/lsb-release already exists in filesystem (owned by manjaro-release)
```

Does anyone know what this is, and how to fix this?
and this was the transaction summary:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall the packages with `sudo pacman -R web-installer-url-handler pamac-snap-plugin pamac-flatpak-plugin`
2. Upgrade the system with `sudo pacman -Syyu`
3. Reinstall the packages `sudo pacman -R web-installer-url-handler pamac-snap-plugin pamac-flatpak-plugin`

Answer (score 1):

sudo rm -r /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/skel/.bashrc /etc/lsb-release

It's says clearly that these file already exists, so just remove it. That may help you.

Comment: I am no manjaro expert, but normally package managers would ask to remove, and brute force root removal is typically not the first line of attack. Has OP searched the manjaro forums?

Comment: I did what you said and now and it almost did it but then again an error: https://pastebin.com/kvya6rwx should I also delete these files as it says?